# Excluir unit do lazarus

Tags: lazarus

Alguém poderia me ajuda em uma questão que eu não consegui decifrar. É o seguinte, eu criei uma unit na qual dei o nome de frmGrupos, pois bem, ela estava dando erro, eu não consegui identificar o erro e resolvi excluir tudo que pertencia a ela e recompilar o executável, e quando tento criar novamente esta unit com o mesmo nome, diz que já tem uma unit com este nome, (frmGrupos), alguém sabe me dizer como e onde posso exclui-la de uma vez por todas para poder criar ela novamente?

Isso tudo é no Lazarus.

Comment: Ela não está declarada em algum lugar em `Uses`?

Answer (score 0):

Para excluir uma unit do projeto vá em [Menu / Projeto / Remover do projeto]:
Selecione a unit desejada.
Verifique se existe algum outro form fazendo referência a unit excluída na cláusula USES.
Veja também em [Menu / Projeto / Exibir fonte do Projeto]:
A lista de units que fazem parte do projeto.